# Print current line number to stdout using ex

Tags: ex-command, posix

I often use `ex` in scripted edits.  I can run several editing commands, and then save the changed file, with no danger of hanging if an `ex` command encounters an error, by running commands like so:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/someregex/somereplacementtext/g' x | ex file.txt
```

To test commands before overwriting the file, I use:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/someregex/somereplacementtext/g' %p 'q!' | ex file.txt
```

However, I've just encountered a need to simply print a certain line number and then exit.

I know the `ex` command "`.=`" will print the current line number when editing interactively.  Unfortunately, I've found that this doesn't print to stdout the way that `p` does.  You can see this for yourself:

```
printf '%s\n' '8p' '8=' 'q!' | ex somefile.txt
```

**How can I make the `.=` command print to stdout from a scripted `ex` instance?**

Comment: Do you need the line number on its own? `.#` will print the current line prefixed with the line number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable line numbering by calling `:set nu`

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'set nu' '%s/Quux/Foo/g' %p 'q!' | ex file.txt
     1  Foo Bar
     2  Foo Foo Bar Bar
     4  Bar Bar Bar
     5  Foo Foo
```